# 'copy' missing files context menu

Tags: 18.04

In a 16.04 'Files' window, at the top where it gives the path to the folder it's showing, there was a context (pop-up) menu which had a 'copy' entry, so you easily copy that folder. It isn't there in 18.04.
[image: see partial screenshot]
Perhaps I'm overlooking something, or perhaps someone else did.

Comment: This is to improve again in future versions, and actually would be fixed now if it were not that Ubuntu ships with an old version of nautilus file manager. Newer versions have a reworked pathbar with full right-click menu, the same as when you would click the folder in the folder view (thus including "copy").

Answer (score 1):

The option is really missed. This is just another illustration of new GNOME modern "user-friendly" decisions.

You can use two workarounds here.

### Workaround 1

As a workaround you can use two steps below:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (for editing address bar)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (for copying the path)

### Workaround 2

Enable location bar and copy with mouse by:

1. Set always-use-location-entry to true

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry 'true'
   ```
2. Click right mouse button on address bar and click *Select All*, followed by *Copy* (or simply drag the selected text to needed location)

---

Note: I reported [bug 1807452 to launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1807452) and [bug 708 to upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/780) to track the error.

Comment: I use the first suggestion frequently. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can simply right click on the folder and copy. When you paste on a text file or terminal the address will be pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You are not continuously going to copy a folder where you are in (and then, inside the current folder that is being copied?). As such, having a shortcut for such drastic operation is not really needed. In my humble opinion, such shortcut is not greatly missed. If you want to copy the entire folder, go out of it (<kbd>Up</kbd>). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy. Simple enough for an operation you do not every day. You can paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) immediately (the copy will have "Copy off" added to its name) or navigate elsewhere before pressing the key combination to paste it there. Sometimes, I think the strip down Gnome developpers tend to do, makes sense. It can make for a more uniform, cleaner and less cluttered experience.

That said, the current version of nautilus, which is *not* shipped with Ubuntu 18.10, has a reworked folder path that provides the full right-click menu you currently have when right-clicking on an empty spot in the folder. That is functionality that makes sense, because it will make that right-click menu always available. Still, that right-click menu does not contain a copy item. For that, first select the folder as described before. Once Ubuntu developers also give up on desktop icon support through the file manager, we will enjoy these new features on Ubuntu.

If your aim was indeed to copy the file path as text to the clipboard, then the approach of N0rbert also involves two simple keystrokes.